Как изменить номер Com порта через скрипт
Всем привет! Нужно написать  скрипт, что бы при добавление новых Com  плат скрипт автоматический менял их номера пропуская Comunication Port (Com1),  а потом  назначил Com2, Com3 и так дале. Вот мой код
import serial.tools.list_ports

def get_available_com_ports():
    ports = serial.tools.list_ports.comports()
    return [port.device for port in ports]

def change_com_ports():
    available_ports = get_available_com_ports()

    # Если COM1 доступен, пропустим его
    if "COM1" in available_ports:
        print("COM1 доступен, пропускаем его.")
        available_ports.remove("COM1")

    # Изменение номеров остальных COM портов
    new_com_port_number = 2
    for port in available_ports:
        try:
            print(f"Изменено имя порта {port} на COM{new_com_port_number}")
            new_com_port_number += 1
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Ошибка при изменении имени порта {port}: {e}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    change_com_ports()

"COM1 доступен, пропускаем его.
Изменено имя порта COM39 на COM2
Изменено имя порта COM38 на COM3"
Однако в диспечтере устройств COM39 и COM38 не меняются.
Как это сделать?

а как реализавать  даный скрипт?

Вероятно, вам придётся менять запись в реестре. Вот я воткнул устройство, имя COM25 нашлось в таких существенных местах в HKLM -  SerialComm\Device\VCP0 и в FTDIBUS\VID PID.... для нескольких ControlSet

А какую проблему вы решаете? Зачем вообще переназначать порты?

для платежных терминалов собираю виндовс со всеми настройками. 3 устройства работают через com порт. Нужно по максимуму автоматизировать настройки
